# Get div and its content at the top on:hover without disturbing other content

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've created a popup which contains multiple boxes. What I'm trying to do is when user hover on any ".deviceboxes" that particular box width should expand and it should be visible over every content on webpage. To achive this I've written ".deviceboxes:hover" worked fine only for first box in row. But when I hover on other boxes it disturb the layout. what should I do to achive this ?

Following is my HTML content

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div id="leftsection">
      <div class="deviceboxes">
            <div id="boxlabel_NetworkDevice_97" class="title">NetworkDevice_97</div>
                <div id="NetworkDevice_97_1" class="cmds">Command 1</div>
                <div id="NetworkDevice_97_0" class="cmds">Command 2</div>
            </div>

      <div class="deviceboxes mrgnleft">
        <div id="boxlabel_NetworkDevice_9" class="title">NetworkDevice_9</div>
        <div id="NetworkDevice_9_1" class="cmds"Command_1</div>
        <div id="NetworkDevice_9_0" class="cmds">Command_2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Following Is a CSS :

```
.modal-body{ overflow: hidden; position: relative;} 
#fetch_commands{ left: 34% !important; width:1000px !important; height:500px; overflow: hidden;}
#leftsection{ float: left; width: 730px; height: 400px; overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden; min-height: 200px;}
#rightsection{position: relative; width: 200px; height: 400px; overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden; margin-left: 10px; padding-left: 20px; }
.netDevices { width:98%; padding: 5px 0px 5px 5px; cursor: pointer;}
.netDevices:hover {background: #406BA3; color: #FFF !important; -webkit-transition: all 1s; -moz-transition: all 1s; -o-transition: all 1s;}
.processing{ background: #006002; color: #FFF;}
.success{ background: none; color: #006002;}
.failed{ background: node; color: #FF0A16;}

.deviceboxes{ float: left; width: 215px; height: 200px; border: 1px solid #666; overflow-x: hidden;-webkit-transition: all 1s; -moz-transition: all 1s; -o-transition: all 1s;}
.deviceboxes:hover{ position:absolute !important; z-index:999999; width:500px !important; -webkit-transition: all 1s; -moz-transition: all 1s; -o-transition: all 1s;}
.title{ width: 100%; text-align: center; background: #000; color:#FFF; padding:10px; cursor: pointer;}
.cmds{ width: 195px; text-align: left; background: none; color:#000; padding:2px; margin-left: 5px; cursor: pointer; overflow-x: hidden; white-space: nowrap;}
.mrgnleft{ margin-left:10px; }
.mrgntop{ margin-top:10px; }
.navbar-inner { min-height: 65px!important; }
```

Comment: You have your `div`s floated left, and then on hover you take them out of the flow by absolutely positioning those.

Comment: I'm programmer actually not UI developer not so good with CSS. could you please explain me in details ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 simple changes you can make.

1. To compensate for the increased width from 215 - 500px, you can set a negative margin, so the following elements are pulled back to their original position. In this case it needs to be 215-500 = `-285px`.
2. Next instead of using `position:absolute`. You can use `position:relative` for all `.deviceboxes` (not just on hover), so it still keeps some impact on the page flow. This also means the z-indexing will work as you want it to.

And as a note, you only need to apply the `transition` settings to the base state, not the `hover` as well, if they are the same. Just saves a couple of bits.

```css
.modal-body {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
#fetch_commands {
    left: 34% !important;
    width:1000px !important;
    height:500px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#leftsection {
    float: left;
    width: 730px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    min-height: 200px;
}
#rightsection {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
.netDevices {
    width:98%;
    padding: 5px 0px 5px 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.netDevices:hover {
    background: #406BA3;
    color: #FFF !important;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s;
    -o-transition: all 1s;
}
.processing {
    background: #006002;
    color: #FFF;
}
.success {
    background: none;
    color: #006002;
}
.failed {
    background: node;
    color: #FF0A16;
}
.deviceboxes {
    float: left;
    position:relative;
    width: 215px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #666;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s;
    -o-transition: all 1s;
}
.deviceboxes:hover {
    margin-right:-285px;
    z-index:999999;
    width:500px !important;
}
.title {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background: #000;
    color:#FFF;
    padding:10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.cmds {
    width: 195px;
    text-align: left;
    background: none;
    color:#000;
    padding:2px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.mrgnleft {
    margin-left:10px;
}
.mrgntop {
    margin-top:10px;
}
.navbar-inner {
    min-height: 65px!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-body">
    <div id="leftsection">
        <div class="deviceboxes">
            <div id="boxlabel_NetworkDevice_97" class="title">NetworkDevice_97</div>
            <div id="NetworkDevice_97_1" class="cmds">Command 1</div>
            <div id="NetworkDevice_97_0" class="cmds">Command 2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="deviceboxes mrgnleft">
            <div id="boxlabel_NetworkDevice_9" class="title">NetworkDevice_9</div>
            <div id="NetworkDevice_9_1" class="cmds">Command_1</div>
            <div id="NetworkDevice_9_0" class="cmds">Command_2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```